# Diablo 3 tag cleanup

Tags: discussion, diablo-3

There has been some major changes to this game with even more to come once the expansion is released.  This invalidates a lot of questions/answers that's on the site right now.  For example, once the AH closes, all the auction house questions will become obselete.  I'd like to propose a cleanup event for all diablo-3 questions on this site based on these updates.

Some recent major changes:

- Difficulty level changes. No more normal/nightmare/hell/inferno/mp0-10, its now normal, hard, expert, master, torment 1-6
- Many class skills reworked
- Level cap will be 70
- Paragon is now account wide with new paragon points to allocate
- AH is shutting down
- New crafting materials
- Itemization 2.0
- etc etc

I will also be posting bounties on interesting but outdated questions in hopes that they'll be updated with new answers.

Suggested Actions (up for debate)

- Add bounties to old but interesting questions
- Answer old questions with updated answers
- Post comments to remind people to update their question/answer
- Add a disclaimer to obselete questions/answers to show its no longer relevant.
- Edit old questions (?)

Comment: Just to make sure I understand how it works (since I haven't read much on it), even without buying the expansion a lot of the core mechanics of the base game will be patched into a significantly different state, right?

Comment: @Sterno Yes, the expansion isn't out yet my core game has been updated yesterday with a lot of new stuff.

Comment: Yup, lot's of changes for everyone. Even those who decide to not give blizzard more money.

Comment: What is the cleanup supposed to be? closing/deleting old now outdated questions? Or what were you thinking of aside from the bounties on updateble questions?

Comment: @Arperum probably a combination.  so far all I've been doing is adding 1 bounty and leaving comments suggesting people update their question/answer.  I really don't want to completely edit a question and change its intent unless it looks like its been abandoned.  For obselete questions (like everything to do with the AH once it shuts down), I'd recommend closure.

Comment: @Arperum and once I play the game more, I'll be posting updated answers to old questions.

Comment: I unabashedly admit I've been too busy playing the game to do the cleanup :P

Comment: Can any mods just go in and close all the questions in this link? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdiablo-3%5D+auction+house

Answer (score 7):

I applaud any effort and/or time spent into updateing updateable questions.

Closing now irrelevant questions is not something that should happen though, since that would be against the current site policy of leaving old questions for dead/outdated games open. [See this meta answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5744) for more information. 
Editing the post to mention that the information sounds good to me.

Look for example at the questions about minecraft alpha/beta. Most of these are completely outdated and not even remotely relevant to the current version anymore.
Other examples would be a MMO/always online game where the servers shut down.(I recall one of these being mentioned earlier in a meta answer, I think it was City of Heroes) These questions are also left open.

Comment: I'm at work currently, I'll have a hunt for the relevant meta discussions about the closing of old questions tonight.

Comment: I think this is the post you are referring to http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5744

Comment: I'm fine with editing in a disclaimer saying the question/answer is out of date.

Comment: @z- That post is at least part of it. I edited it in, and added your suggestion of adding in a disclaimer.

Comment: I agree with badp though that editing the disclaimer in will bump it to the top of the page, which is kinda silly

Comment: @z- We've done cleanups with less action before (removing bad tags etc) which completely spammed the frontpage. I don't consider it a serious problem over the larger problem of having outdated info. Especially considering how fast the front page moves most of the time. The bumped posts would be off the front page in an hour or two at most.

Comment: @Arperum - I'd also like to add that with the ability for the Minecraft Launcher to go back to any previous version of the game (including Alpha and Beta versions), *any Minecraft question and/or answer dealing with mechanics pertaining to these versions will remain relevant*.

Comment: @Robotnik Dammit "new" minecraft launcher. I'm not used to it, I've been playing modded minecraft since before that launcher came up. So I'm not used to it.

Comment: Spamming the front page is a problem for a few hours to a small set of people. Outdated information is a much longer problem to a wider set of people.

Comment: @Vaishali When it makes sense to because the question itself is different, sure. But take for example [this new question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/157840/with-the-recently-patch-2-0-1-where-are-the-key-wardens-and-whats-the-drop-rat), which is a dupe of an existing one because the question is still the same. The answer has just changed.

Comment: One problem with reusing old questions, like the one about the key wardens, is that existing answers may now be wildly wrong but still have 37 upvotes. It's going to be quite some time before new and (now) correct answers accrue enough upvotes to beat the old one. additionally, there are accepted answers that may be wrong, are you going to forcibly un-accept wrong answers?

Comment: Note that questions regarding old minecraft version might not be the best template for how to handle Diablo 3 since it's perfectly legal to start up an old Minecraft version, but with the way Diablo 3 goes online to play, you will (probably) have to upgrade, which means it's unlikely (impossible?) to play using the old version now. In other words, if you have to be online, and patched, old incorrect answers will only be valuable for historical reasons, which by itself means they should be kept, but that in turn votes in favor (at least to me) for *not* reusing old questions.

Comment: Note that I'm not commenting regarding closing old questions, but the key warden question was closed as a duplicate. If the existing answers to the duplicate question, which has been accepted, and have 37 upvotes, is now completely incorrect, in my opinion the new question is *not* a duplicate.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen its still a duplicate, all we can do is remind people to accept the new and correct answer that's already been posted.